# Not able to use langchain agent create_sql_agent with CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION agent type

Tags: sql, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api

```
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["query"],
    template="{query}"
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")


agent = create_sql_agent(
    llm = llms,
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory,
    prompt=prompt,
    agent_type=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    # return_intermediate_steps=True,
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
)
```

Getting Error - ValueError: Agent type AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION not supported at the moment.

PS:I Cant use Zeroshot since i need to use memory.

Tried

chat-conversational-react-description and AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION

Answer (score 1):

If look at the source code, we will find that create_sql_agent does not support this agent type.

[image]

Here is [source code](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/1cd9d5f3328e144cbe5d6ef52a22029d4fdf0cce/libs/langchain/langchain/agents/agent_toolkits/sql/base.py#L28).